# Get default text font for Table Cell labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I want to create a custom table cell and a custom header containing other views.  As far as I can see I need to add all labels and views to the contentView property (of a UITableViewCell / UITableViewHeaderFooterView object I create).  I want to set the label fonts to be the default fonts used in iOS for textLabel and detailTextLabel, but these are different on iOS 6 and 7.  Is there any way I can get the current default style for those labels?

Comment: Why not just create a `UITableViewCell` and ask it for `cell.textLabel.font`

Comment: I tried that, it's `nil`.  I'm not sure when it gets initialised.  Same for `.textColor`

Comment: cant you use prototype cells? in interface builder? make sure you set it after the view/cell loaded, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically.